# MySQL auto increment inverted

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I've executed two `INSERT`s on the same table in rapid succession
with the `last_insert_id` of the first query I've populated a field for the second one.

The table has auto increment on the Primary Key.

Everything works fine but in one occasion that's what happened:

The first `INSERT` returns `last_insert_id` i.e. 1000

The second `INSERT` returns `id` `999` and in the record, the field populated with the key of the prior `INSERT` is `1000`.

I hadn't noticed this behavior anymore.

How can this happen?

EDITED ----

I can't post the code, the INSERT query is created automatically by a class I've built, but i can reproduce the algorithm:

1 - Save with an INSERT record #1

2 - Get id of #1

{3} - If there are more records to be memorized

4 - Foreach record #X save with id_refer = id#1

The instructions are consequential and not asynchronous.

The table is InnoDB, no transactions the table is the same for every INSERT

Comment: Can you show the code which does this?  I suspect you're inserting the records and getting the inserted identifiers in a relatively unreliable manner, crossing some wires as it were somewhere in your code.

Comment: "Rapid Succession" may be resulting in the second insert retrieving an id prior to the first id, but I would expect that to be extremely difficult to produce

Comment: But for that to happen the two insertion requests, being sent in the order A, B to be reverted somewhere in between to result in first B to be inserted, than A?!

Comment: You should provide both the queries and the code used to execute them.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  For one thing, are we talking about MyISAM or InnoDB?  Are there any transactions involved?  Same connection doing both `INSERTs`?